# youtube-dl removing downloaded parts

Tags: video, downloads, ffmpeg, youtube-dl, mp4

youtube-dl downloads mp4 parts and after downloading, combines that parts to make a single mp4 video file. I don't want a single, combined mp4 file. Because i want to edit those mp4.part files myself. Any idea how to revert deleting those parts?

Comment: `youtube-dl -k`. For more information, call `youtube-dl -h`

Comment: @ridgy not worked i'm afraid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to rg3/youtube-dl from github, next release will have the
--keep-fragments option. The current release of youtube-dl is 2017.04.17.

Comment: In fact version 2017.05.14 contains this option as you have suggested...